# how to define arraysize in oracle as we do in java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

In java :

```
Date d[] = new Date[2];
Date temp[] = {new Date(),new Date()};
```

In Oracle

```
temp date = (sysdate,sysdate);--it works
```

but how to define size of temp as 2 as we do in java code.

Comment: Doesn't the manual describe how to do this?

Comment: If you are new to databases (or programming in general) the first thing you should learn, is how to find information in the manual. You won't get very far if you need to ask questions even for the most simple syntax problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I understand the question.  You've tagged it for PL/SQL so I assume that your "in Oracle" code is intended to be syntactically correct PL/SQL code but what you've posted isn't valid syntax.

In PL/SQL, you have three different types of collections.  You have nested tables, associative arrays, and varrays.  You do not declare a size for nested tables or associative arrays at compile time-- they will use whatever space they need.  You do declare a size for varrays at compile time so you can declare a varray that stores two dates.  I can't envision a case where I would ever want to declare a varray of size 2 rather than using a nested table, though, since you get no benefit from limiting yourself to a 2 element collection.  If you want to, though, you can declare the varray as I do below.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    -- Nested table
  3    type date_nt is table of date;
  4    -- Associative array
  5    type date_aa is table of date index by pls_integer;
  6    -- VArray
  7    type date_va is varray(2) of date;
  8    l_date_nt date_nt := date_nt( sysdate, sysdate );
  9    l_date_va date_va := date_va( sysdate, sysdate );
 10    l_date_aa date_aa;
 11  begin
 12    l_date_aa(1) := sysdate;
 13    l_date_aa(100) := sysdate;
 14* end;
 15  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```